# Exec through PHP. I cant get the output (stderr) into a file

Tags: php, apache, ffmpeg, command, stderr

When I run exec() through php, I fail to get the output (stderr) into a file.

I've included **"2> my_out_put_file.txt"** at the end of my command to accomplish this. But when I include this, the command is not executed. However, if I run the command without **"2> my_out_put_file.txt"** then it works.

The interesting thing is that the whole command, even with **"2> my_out_put_file.txt"** at the end of the command works if I run directly via shell/promt, but not when I run it through php / apache.

**Does not work:**

exec("C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i $new_path/$filename_with_ext -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile:v main -acodec aac $new_path/$filename.mp4 **2> out.txt**", $a, $b);

**Works:**

exec("C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i $new_path/$filename_with_ext -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile:v main -acodec aac $new_path/$filename.mp4", $a, $b);

Best regards
Neo

Comment: Most likely, you aren't running the same commands in PHP and in command-prompt. The shell cannot see your interpolated PHP variables in the string, the only thing that counts is the final string rendered. I suggest you dump or inspect the actual command.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
... 2>&1 >> log.txt
```

Tested from exec too:

```
php -r "exec('ffmpeg -version 2>&1 >> log.txt');"
```